# Android: How to make inverted border radius?

Tags: android, android-drawable

[image]

How to make shape like on image?
Bottom left and right corners is simple. But top left and right corners...
radius="-10dp" won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more complex shapes such as the one you are looking for you are better off using either vector or PNG resources than shape drawables.

Shape drawables are great for very simple shapes, but don't support a full suite of drawing options.